# Why is there a second outline in my html and how to remove it?

Tags: html, css, border

I've got a second outline that is showing up when I click on the input field.
Why is it happening and how do I solve it so the white portion doesn't show up.
I used the outline colour to be red while I was developing to make sure I'm writing the right code. To my limited CSS knowledge the white part should not be displayed.

```css
.Search-bar{  /*This is the component I need help with*/
height: 30px;
width: 300px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: none;
background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
text-align: center;
}
.Search-bar:hover{
width: 600px;
border: none;
}

.Search-bar:focus{
outline-color: red; /*I'm giving red to show contrast*/
}

.Navigation-bar {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
color: white;
box-shadow: 0px 2.98px 7.45px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}


.Nav-list {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
}
 
.Nav-list-title-button {
margin-left: 15px;
color: white;
border: none;
background: 100px;
height: 60px;
width: 160px;
font-size: larger;
}

.Nav-list-title-button:hover {
color: grey;
}
 
.Nav-list-button {
color: white;
margin: auto;
border: none;
background: 100px;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
font-size: large;
}

.Nav-list-button:hover {
color: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav className="Navigation-bar">
    <button className="Nav-list-title-button">Quests &#38; Fiction</button>
    <SearchBar />
    <div className="Nav-list">
        <button className="Nav-list-button">Log In</button>
        <button className="Nav-list-button">Register</button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is how it looks.
[image: How the Navsigation Bar Looks]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the outline from the input field.

```css
.search {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search..">
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep the outline. I don't undertand why there is white with the red in the outline.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the browser that highlight the outline. Why don't you use border instead?

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.Search-bar {
  /*This is the component I need help with*/
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.Search-bar:hover {
  /* width: 600px; */
  /* border: none; */
}

.Search-bar:focus {
  outline: red;
  /*I'm giving red to show contrast*/
  border-color: red;
}

.Navigation-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.98px 7.45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.Nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.Nav-list-title-button {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: larger;
}

.Nav-list-title-button:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.Nav-list-button {
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  background: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: large;
}

.Nav-list-button:hover {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav className="Navigation-bar">
  <button className="Nav-list-title-button">Quests &#38; Fiction</button>
  <div><input type="text" class="Search-bar"></div>
  <div className="Nav-list">
    <button className="Nav-list-button">Log In</button>
    <button className="Nav-list-button">Register</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```